# Set WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot in .NET code instead of web.config

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS WIT in a web application and I am currently setting the cache folder for work items (used by TFS API) in the web.config

I want to set this in code, as I want to use the users default temorary files folder path from Path.GetTempFolderPath.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Could this be the answer you are looking for?

(from [here](http://berg-henry.blogspot.com/2010/07/connecting-to-tfs2010-from-webpart.html))

The application setting can be created in `web.config` or programmatically

`web.config`:

```
<appSettings> <!-- Add reference to TFS Client Cache -->
   <add key="WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot" value="C:\TFSClientCache" />
</appSettings>
```

Code:

```
if (WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot"] == null || WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot"] == String.Empty)
{
   WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WorkItemTrackingCacheRoot"] = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "TFSClientCache";
}
```

Comment: I used this technique successfully to control the TFS client using a folder path derived from an external source.  Very nice!